# structure value is completely wrong number

Tags: c++

I am attempting to create a code that essentially is supposed to create hypothetical enemy's to fight, with their stats being contained in a struct (health, armor, and exp with the exp being calculated based on the health and armor). I am in my first steps trying to define a struct and make sure it calculates the exp correctly, instead of printing 2 it prints 13743895 and I have been unsuccessful in changing it.
Here is my code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct stats
{
    int health;
    int armor;
    int exp = (health * armor)/50;
};

int main()
{
    stats enemy;
    enemy.health = 10;
    enemy.armor = 10;
    printf("%i\n", enemy.exp);
}
```

The only things I have been able to do is to set the number to something static within the struct, then it will print the number I set it to, I have also set exp as something to be individually defined like the others and it works. However it is stated that I need to do this calculation within my code, and I am unable to integrate it.

Comment: because theyre not initialized when you evaluate exp. that expression doesnt get evaluated when you request it it gets evaluated when the object,s constructor runs which is *before* you actually set both of them to 10, before that both values are inderminate. compile with warnings enabled your compiler should yell at your for this. (P.S: my comment was written before someone retagged from C++ to C)

Comment: You seem to believe that, when you initialize `int exp = (health * armor)/50;` , then `exp` will somehow magically update itself whenever `health` or `armor` are updated. This is not the case. Rather than making `exp` a data member, make it a member function, as in `int exp() const { return (health * armor)/50; }` This way, the value will in fact be computed using current values of `health` and `armor` whenever you call `exp()`

Comment: To whoever changed the tag to C, this is C++ and is not legal C.